# How to Check if type of Map extends Number

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types

I'm trying to check if a `Map<String, T>` contains Objects (T) of type Double or Integer.

I don't want to use the actual Objects in the map for checking the class since It's not certain that the Map contains Objects at all.

I can achieve this by doing the following (Assuming the field is containing a Map):

```
ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType(); 

isNumeric(type);

/**
 * @param type
 * @return Returns true if type is numeric
 */
private static boolean isNumeric(ParameterizedType type) {
    return  type.getActualTypeArguments()[1].toString().equals("? extends java.lang.Number");
}
```

It's sufficient for me but it doesn't feel like a clean solution.

However, I can retrieve the Type of the `getActualTypeArguments()[1]`
by doing the following:

```
Type typeOfSecondGeneric = type.getActualTypeArguments()[1]; // equals '? extends java.lang.Number'
```

I can't use `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(typeOfSecondGeneric); // Class expected`

After I researched a bit, I didn't came up with a better solution than doing the String comparison.

What am I getting wrong?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you declare your maps as `Map<String, T extends Number>` instead, and use `Number#doubleValue()` or `Number#intValue()` as appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in charge of editing the Maps. I just get a bunch of fields representing the member variables of an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ad hoc solution could be something like this:

```
private static boolean isNumericValue(ParameterizedType t) {
    return isSubclassOf(t.getActualTypeArguments()[1], Number.class);
}

private static boolean isSubclassOf(Type t, Class<?> clazz) {
    if (t instanceof Class<?>)
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) t);
    if (t instanceof ParameterizedType)
        return isSubclassOf(((ParameterizedType) t).getRawType(), clazz);
    Type[] bounds = null;
    if (t instanceof TypeVariable<?>)
        bounds = ((TypeVariable<?>) t).getBounds();
    if (t instanceof WildcardType)
        bounds = ((WildcardType) t).getUpperBounds();
    if (bounds != null && bounds.length > 0)
        return isSubclassOf(bounds[0], clazz);
    return clazz == Object.class;
}
```

That short example doesn't handle interface types or generic array types. It's also nowhere near to being complete with respect to the actual rules of subtyping.

If it's true that you really do need something like this, I think the better solution is to use [Guava `TypeToken`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html):

```
private static final TypeToken<Map<?, ? extends Number>> T =
    new TypeToken<Map<?, ? extends Number>>() {};

private static boolean isNumericValue(ParameterizedType t) {
    return T.isSupertypeOf(t);
}
```

That said, I'm not all that convinced that you do need this. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you might do better asking a question about the problem you're trying to solve rather than your attempted solution. This is the kind of code that can turn in to a huge pain in the neck after your program is tied down to using it, especially if it's pervasive.

Answer (score 1):

This information is lost at run-time so in general you won't be able to figure out what `T` really is.

The exception to this general rule are limited to those case in where the map object class itself has a more specific constraint on that `T`. For example:

```
class MyDoubleMap<K> extends Map<K, Double> {
...
}    
...
Map<String, Double> standard = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> doubles = new MyDoubleMap<>();
Map<String, Double> annonDoubles = new HashMap<>() {};
```

With `standard` any reflection trick won't be able to recover more than `T` and that it could be anything that extends `Object`.

However for the other two cases `doubles` and `annonDoubles` the reflection code included in other answer should get to the `Double` assignation to the `T`.

With `doubles` it should be easy to see that that information should be available thru reflection as it is integral part of this declaration of `MyDoubleMap`. Perhaps 
`annonDoubles` is a bit less obvious but in fact with the trailing `{}` it is effectively declaring an anonymous 
inner class that extends `HashMap<String, Double>` and so such an information for `T` (and also for `K`) can be recovered by reflection.

Comment: Field types are stored in the class file, so if they're obtaining the parameterized type from `Field.getGenericType()` there's no reason to use anonymous classes. `Field.getGenericType()` returns the type declared in the source code for the class, not the type of its actual value (which would be erased, as you say).